# Setting up of a price for in-app products

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

We have a product whose price is $999. Google do not allow to set up price above $400. Is there any way I can set up the price as $400?

[image: IN-app product price limited to $400]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the [Supported locations for distribution to Google Play Users](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286) that yes, you can set it up to $400 only.

[image]